# how do i plot hysteresis using matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to model memristor using its equation in exponential mode using Matlab . My aim is to just get the hysteresis plot(i-v plot) in Matlab. the equation is like

```
i=x^n*b*sinh(av)+m(exp(gv)-1)
x'=Af(x)h(v)
```

where `f(x)` is window function and `h(v)` is polynomial function, `A` is constant.

```
f(x)=1-(2x-1)^2
h(v)=cv+dv^3;
```

`c` and `d` are constant  `c<0` & `d>0`
`a=2;` `b=0.01;` `g=4;` `n=4;` `A=25;` `m=0.001;`

`x` is internal state of device..is it possible to get plot in matlab?
I have tried in matlab it is showing errors

Comment: Please show us your try and associated errors.

Answer (score 1):

This script I found on google after a very brief search:
http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/skva/Memristor%20Models/MATLAB/memristor.m

You can choose there what kind of model do you want to use (Nonlinear Ion Drift model in your case), the type of window function (yours is Jogelkar's I assume) and nonlinear voltage-current relation.

After modifying a bit their script you should get something like this:

```
b=0.01; g=4; n=4; a=2;A=25; m=0.001;
c=-1;d=4;%your constants
numOfPoints = 10000;
t = linspace(-1, 1,numOfPoints);
dt = t(2) - t(1);
volt = .003*sin(2*pi*t);
x = zeros(size(t));
curr = x;
for i=2:numOfPoints
    x(i) = x(i-1) + A*(c*volt(i)+d*(volt(i))^3)*(1-(2*x(i-1)-1)^2)*dt;
    curr(i)=x(i)^n*b*sinh(a*volt(i))+m*(exp(g*volt(i))-1);
end;
fig = figure(1);
plot(volt,curr);
xlabel('Voltage');ylabel('Current');
figure(fig);
```

Good luck!